# Can one move a chat back to comments?

Tags: support, comments, chat

How can I move a chat back to comments?

In complying to the automated admonition to move comments to chat, I discovered that MathJax is was no longer rendered.  This is unacceptable in this particular discussion.  I therefore need to undo my action and move the chat back to comments.

Comment: MathJax can be rendered in chat, it just isn't done automatically. [See this link for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97938/any-chance-of-mathjax-in-chat/220976#220976).

Comment: I followed that link, discovered that it has further links to further instructions some of which are obsolete and direct you to other things ... so I popped back to the SE chat extension for Google Chrome, installed, activated it, verified it was active and then relotted the chat.   No effect.  This is not acceptable.  How can I move the chat back where I know it will render for the participants I have just injured by moving to chat?

Comment: Have you got a link to the chat room in question? I'll check whether the MathJax renders for me.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91368/discussion-between-james-bowery-and-vladimir-kalitvianski

Comment: [That renders fine](https://imgur.com/a/pT8FKHv). There's obviously just some hiccup in the MathJax scripts on your browser.

Comment: There is no way to move a chat back to comments. Indeed, the SE policy is specifically that comments should not be used for discussions, so even if you approach the SE directly they are unlikely to move the chat back.

Comment: There was a conflicting Chrome extension:  MathJax for Chrome™. I turned it off, replotted and it still didn't render.  I then switched developer mode on.  Replotted, and it rendered.  I turned developer mode off, replotted and it still rendered.  What SE should do is provide a link on the chat page to the appropriate extensions for your browser, with adequate instructions including eliminating conflicts such as I encountered.

Comment: Interestingly, the SE MathJax Chrome Extension does not render transcripts:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/91368

Comment: Ironically I am now being prompted to move this conversation to chat :-)

Comment: I can get MathJax in that transcript by using a ChatJax bookmarklet script. I'm using the Samsung Android browser, which is very similar to the Android Chrome browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to move a chat to comments. Comments are transient and not intended for extended discussions, while chat is permanent and intended for many types of discussions.